# How to write shorter css code select child?

Tags: css

How to write shorter css code select child?
example:
Q1. if I try to select `.l1` `.l3` in `.a`

I need to write `.a` 2 times , if I have to select 4 child div I need to write 4 times.... 
any other syntax in css?

```
.a .l1, .a .l3{
}


<div class="a">
    <div class="l1">
    </div>
    <div class="l2">
    </div>
    <div class="l3">
    </div>
    <div class="l4">
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS can be verbose in this sort of situation. Very often there is a lot of repetition, and not much you can do about it.

Repeating the `.a` part of the selector in this case is hardly the worst case; it's actually relatively short and clear. I wouldn't worry about it.

If you are still worried about it, there are a few options I can offer:

- `nth-child()`
  This selector allows you to pick elements within a group based on a regular pattern. For example, `.a nth-child(2n-1)` will select every second element, starting at the first, so `l1` and `l3`, which matches your requirements in the question.

  However, your example was fairly small; it's not clear whether this would be a good match for your requirements beyond the first couple of matches. `nth-child` is really only good for regular patterns; if you need to pick random arbitrary elements in the list, it may not be suitable. And even if it is suitable, older browsers like IE8 do not support it (this can be solved with javascript polyfills like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) though).
- Use a CSS preprocessor like [SASS or Less](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/).
  Both SASS and Less give you a whole new syntax for your CSS code, which allow clever things like nesting of related styles, variables, etc. In your case, this would allow you to write code like this:

  ```
  .a {
      .l1, .l3 {
          /* styles go here */
      }
  }
  ```

  That may be exactly what you're looking for?

  The down-side here is that it **isn't CSS**. It needs to be processed by the SASS or Less processor and turned into CSS before the browser can understand it. This would usually be done as part of your site deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all divs then you can just use:

```
.a div{

}
```

If those divs contain other divs then you're probably best to use a child selector to avoid them inheriting the parent styles:

```
.a + div{

 }
```

If you're selecting all but one (say the 3rd) then you could use:

```
.a div:not(:nth-child(3)){

}
```

:nth-child is only supported in IE9+ so this will depend on what browsers you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, under these circumstances:

```
.a div:nth-child(odd) {
    /* first, third, etc */
}
```